# How to copy SPIR-V Private storage-qualified matrix array into Function storage-qualified matrix array?

Tags: vulkan, spir-v

I am fighting with driver bug, and long story short i have created OpVariables with proper data in invocation-level global memory, aka Private storage-qualified OpVariable of type float4x3[6].

Now, i need this data converted to Function storage qualifier, as OpVariables in OpFunction scope. But i am kind of lost about when do i apply what copying operations, especially with matrices and arrays, and I have both at once. Do i just OpLoad and OpStore? Or do i need to OpLoad, OpCompositeExtract each matrix from indices, OpCompositeConstruct from them and only afterwards OpStore? The SPIR-V specification on the subject is rather dense, and i cannot seem to find one place where copying operations are described. The rules are probably scattered all over the spec.

Answer (score 2):

After some experimentation it seems that all that is required to convert variables from Private to Function is simple OpLoad(Private) and OpStore to Function variable.

Comment: You may also want to use OpCopyMemory